# How to enable guifg guibg in vim?

Tags: vim, color-scheme, 256color

As the title says, I want to know how can I enable the `guifg` and `guibg` in vim colorschemes. I already wrote in my vimrc `set t_Co=256`, but it enables only `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` for 256 colors.

I have Debian 7.0 wheezy and I'm using `gnome-terminal` (but I tried with `terminator terminal` and also doesn't work)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: "gui"bg and "gui"fg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highlight attributes starting with `gui..=` are only ever used in GVIM, not in terminal Vim; in the GUI, 24-bit colors are available, but most terminals stop at supporting 256 different colors.

Plugins like [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) can take the GUI color definitions and convert them to a closely matching 256-color `cterm` color palette for high-color terminals. This helps with colorschemes that otherwise only pick from the bland default 16-color terminal color palette, or only provide GUI color definitions.

Comment: CSApprox works very well.  There is also https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/vim-csexact which offers a slightly different approach to the problem.  Both are work checking out.